# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s error only on 64 bit iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone-5, xcode5

I am receiving a ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s error but only when I run it on the iPhone 64 bit. It works for 32 bit phones with iOS6 and iOS7 and also works on the 64 bit iOS7 simulator. These are the errors I am receiving.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "*RKMIMETypeJSON", referenced from:

      _*_38-[ServiceCalls saveSupportInformation]_block_invoke in ServiceCalls.o
      ___53-[ServiceCalls saveHealthJournalEntry:healthJournal:]_block_invoke_2 in    ServiceCalls.o
      ___26-[ServiceCalls sendEmail:]_block_invoke in ServiceCalls.o
      ___59-[ServiceCalls createMailFolder:inParentFolder:forMailbox:]_block_invoke_2 in    ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKManagedObjectStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKJSONParserJSONKit", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKParserRegistry", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectPropertyInspector", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MappingSerializerFactory.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMappingOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RKReflectiveObjectManager in RKReflectiveObjectManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectRelationshipMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RKReflectiveObjectManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKManagedObjectMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RKReflectiveObjectManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKDynamicObjectMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RKReflectiveObjectManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FMHMobileAppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in RKReflectiveObjectManager.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RKReflectiveObjectManager in RKReflectiveObjectManager.o
      objc-class-ref in ServiceCalls.o

I have made sure to import all my .m files in compile sources and imported all the right things under link binary with libraries. 
I have also checked all the files and they all import files ending with .h.
I have also tried deleting everything from Library Search Paths which removes those errors but then gives me a ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics error.

Again, this works on all phones and simulators except for the 64 bit iPhone. It even works on the 64 bit simulator though.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT:**

The problem ended up being that RestKit did not support armv7s yet. I changed my valid architectures to only be armv7 and it worked on all devices.

Comment: This could be related to CocoaPods. Try `gem install cocoapods` to update it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I forgot to mention that I tried that also. I updated my question with how I got it to work.

Comment: I have the same errors , do you solve it ? Thanks a lot