# Linkage error with Xcode 6.1.1, RestKit 0.9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, restkit, armv7

I've inherited an iOS project which uses RestKit, version 0.9.  I'm getting link errors when I try to build it, as follows:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKManagedObjectStore", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MySettings.o
      "_RKMIMETypeJSON", referenced from:
          -[TrackerViewController btnAdd:] in TrackerViewController.o
          -[MainViewController request:didLoadResponse:] in MainViewController.o
          -[MainViewController uploadUnscored] in MainViewController.o
          -[MyListController btnUpload] in MyListController.o
          -[MyListController getList:] in MyListController.o
          -[MyListController btnFood] in MyListController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MySettings.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRequestSerialization", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in TrackerViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MyListController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKParserRegistry", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in TrackerViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in NyListController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKClient", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in TrackerViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
          objc-class-ref in MyListController.o
          (etc.)
```

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1. I connected the Restcode project by dragging in onto the app project from FileManager - the original code was archived without the link to RestKit (i.e. it was showing up in red).

There are a few postings about this, but I haven't been able to work out the correct solution. For example, one solution ([ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s error only on 64 bit iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036282/ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7s-error-only-on-64-bit-iphone)) suggests changing the architecture to just armv7, but it doesn't doesn't work. Another example suggests "then modify the dependency library so it has armv7 as a target too", but it was already a target.  Another answer suggests "change the Base SDK of the RestKit project to Lastest iOS, and re-add all the necessary Frameworks.", but it was already set to the latest iOS.

Valid Architectures in the Restkit project do specify armv6, armv7 and armv7s, but since the error is about amrv7, I don't think that's the issue. I also set the "build active architecture only" to "no", but again receive the same suite of errors.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Show the restkit build settings in a screenshot, something means it isn't building for that version. If you're using a really old version then you need to change the project to have newer versions built...

Comment: I have the same Issues , Could you help me if you solve the errors . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got back to this after a week, and got it resolved. It could have been one of three things:

1) I followed the README.md instructions that came with the distribution as carefully as possible.
2) The project had 3 targets, and they all had to be linked with RestKit.